# only sum up pattern inside parentheses, bash

Tags: bash, shell

Good day respected colleagues,

Today, I was wondering how to know how many `;` are inside square parentheses `[]`.

Example:

```
[lipsum;limpsum;lipsum;lipsum] lipsum;limpsum;lipsum;lipsum
```

Thanks so much in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk one liner:

```
s='[lipsum;limpsum;lipsum;lipsum] lipsum;limpsum;lipsum;lipsum'
awk -F '\\[|\\]' '{split($2, a, ";"); print length(a)-1}' <<< "$s"
3
```

Using grep and wc:

```
egrep -o '\[.*\]' <<< "$s"|grep -o ';'|wc -l
3
```

Comment: @ anubhava, thanks so much! it works from me with the addition of "$s" instead of "s". But it works! : )

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo, should have been `$s`